# Dividing menu to different parts in Joomla CMS

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to divide a menu such that I can have different items of menu in different boxes in the design .
For example There are item 1, item 2,..., item 10  and I want to arrange the item 1 to 5 in box1 in my design and item 6 to 10 in box2.

Is there any way to do this?

Right now I have hard-coded the menu items but it is not a firm solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are organizing the menus, without any details it's hard to say. The simplest solution is to put the menu items in to different menus, then use multiple menu modules that can be positioned where ever you like on the screen. You should never have to hard code a menu.

Comment: I am going to try this, but seems to be the best option . Thank you